# Access only mydomain_name/filename.html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I need to deny access for all excluded URLs:

mydomainname/filename.html

and redirect this request to:

mydomainname/index.php?page=filename.html

And the user should see in the address bar:

mydomainname/filename.html

And I want all styles and js scripts to work correctly.

How can I do this?

I am was trying this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
ErrorDocument 403 /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\w+)(?=\.).html$ index.php?page=$1.html

#if the request is for existent dirs, forbid the request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$    
RewriteRule !^index.php$ - [R,F,L]

Options All -Indexes
```

And I have server error 500.

Without "Options All -Indexes" js files can't be loaded and styles are not working.

Answer (score 0):

So, my final .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 403 http://mydomainname
ErrorDocument 404 http://mydomainname

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes
# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Internal redirect
RewriteRule ^(\w+)(?=\.).html$ index.php?page=$1.html

# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]
```

This solution is not deny access to mydomainname/include/myfile.php (if this file is exist), but it cover all other issues.

Answer (score -1):

Search for rewrite condition in .htaccess file. You will get an idea for it. Or add RewriteRule ^(.*).(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ /public/$1.$2 [L,NC] this.

Comment: This does not even begin to answer the OP's question.